# How to list all controllers in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am looking how to find all controllers in the ember app. I am using ember 1.6.
I know how to fins one controller by given name:

`var myController = window.App.__container__.lookup('controller:myController ');`

Is there a way to list all controllers?

Comment: Why do you require this ?. It would be good if you share use case for this. By the way you can try for specific controller - `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('controller:myController ') ` - not sure about the version compatible of getOwner support

Comment: @kumkanillam `getOwner` comes with Ember 2.3. [Ref](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_injected-container-access). But the same question: "why do you require this?"

Comment: Ember itself has no public API for that. Maybe you can use your build tool or your loader for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Here is the function which will return all controllers:

```
function getAllControllers(){
    var controllers = [];
    for (var prop in window.App.__container__.cache.dict){
       if (prop.indexOf('controller') > -1){
          console.log(prop);
          controllers.push(SDC.__container__.lookup(prop));
       }
    }
    return controllers;
}
```